# What are the main results of graph theory?

Tags: graph-theory

A friend recommended me to take a course in graph theory. I had some exposure to graph theory in a CS course but this particular branch of mathematics didn't seem to be very rigorous or self-contained in the sense there are memorable theorems, lemmas or widely known applications.

In fact, graph theory is quite empirical. Given any graph, most results could be derived through method of induction. I just don't see any amazing significance of taking an entire course in graph theory. This is in contrast with more traditional math disciplines such as calculus or complex analysis, where the results are truly not obvious and there are cornerstones in both branches (i.e. fundamental theorem of calculus or cauchy integral theorem comes to mind). I just don't see any key results coming from graph theory.

Can someone who is familiar with this branch of mathematics tell me some of the most important results that graph theory can offer and how does this branch of mathematics connect with other branches?

Comment: Probably a good example is [Kuratowski's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuratowski%27s_theorem)

Comment: @lisyarus That theorem is a lot more powerful than the Wikipedia page makes it out to be.

Comment: @Alizter could you elaborate a little?

Comment: @lisyarus Essentially it gives a very good understanding of planar graphs which is an area of graph theory that dips its toes into lots of other areas of mathematics.

Comment: I suggest you to look at the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reconstruction_conjecture. It is an example of simple stated and very hard problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Graph theory is rigorous and definitely not empyrical, I don't know where you get those ideas.

It is linked for example with optimization in some sense, when we consider directed wighted graphs and want to know what is the cheapest way to go from one vertex to another, which indeed is what a GPS does.

It is also related in a deeper sense when talking about the Simplex algorithm that moves through the vertices of a polytope, the (disproved) Hirsch conjecture and the generalized d-steps conjecture in order to exactly know why the simplex works good when Klee has proved that its complexity is exponential.

About main results, I think four color theorem is by large the most known, that was open for around 200 years if I remember correctly.